# bash to rename file in directory using partial match to another file

Tags: bash

In the below I am trying to rename the contents within each `data` subfolder in a specific run, based on a partial match of the `IonCode_0000_` in each file pair in the `data` subdirectory to `$1` in `f1`. There will be multiple runs in `f1` but each run in `$uniq` is unique and will be found in `f1` and the rename values in `$2`. The below code is commented as to what I think is going on. Thank you :).

The `set -x` is good up to `Rename from:IonCode_0404 to:00-0000-xxx-xxx-xxx IonCode_0402 11-1111-yy-yy-yyy`, but I am not sure why this is or how to fix it. I apologize for the long post I just wanted to include all the details as Ihave been unable to solve this. Thank you :).

**Contents of data**  --- these are the pairs of files to rename ----

```
IonCode_0402_xxx_xxx_xxx.bam
IonCode_0402_xxx_xxx_xxx.bam.bai
IonCode_0404_xxx_xxx_xxx.bam
IonCode_0404_xxx_xxx_xxx.bam.bai
```

**f1**  --- this is the file that the rename partial matches comes from ---

```
IonCode_0404 00-0000-xxx-xxx-xxx
IonCode_0402 11-1111-yy-yy-yyy
R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_xx1-127-xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xx_xx_xx

IonCode_0402 22-2222-zz-zzzz-zzz
R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_xx1-126-xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xx_xx_xx
```

**current dara after rename**  --- only one pair renamed with both values from `f1`

```
IonCode_0402_xxx.xxx_xxx.bam
IonCode_0402_xxx.xxx_xxx.bam.bai
00-0000-xxx-xxx-xxx IonCode_0402 11-1111-yy-yy-yyy_test.bam.bam
00-0000-xxx-xxx-xxx IonCode_0402 11-1111-yy-yy-yyy_test.bam.bam.bai
```

**desired data after rename**

```
11-1111-yy-yy-yyy_test.bam
11-1111-yy-yy-yyy_test.bam.bai
00-0000-xxx-xxx-xxx_test.bam
00-0000-xxx-xxx-xxx_test.bam.bai
```

**bash**

```
set -x
dir=$1
for f in "$dir" ; do  ## operate on desired directory
  uniq=${dir##*/}  ## store run with no path as uniq
while read from to  ## start loop using from to
do
 (
   cd "$dir"/data  ## change directory to subfolder $from
   echo "Rename from:$from to:$to"  ## echo files
   for file in *.bam* 
   do
      newname=${file/$from*.bam/${to}_test.bam} ## rename adding text
      [ -f "$file" ] && [ "$newname" != "$file" ] && mv "$file" "$newname"  ## if names in uniq change file name
   done
 )
done <<<$(
   awk -F '\n' -v RS="" -v ref="$uniq" ' ## filter to this run in uniq
     $0 ~ ref {
         d=split($0, val); ## split on newline and space
         for(i=1;i<d;i++) print val[i];
      }' "$dir"/f1  
)  ## loop through f1 for unique run and populate from and to
done
```

Comment: Is there a better way or can someone see what I am missing. The above seems right to me. Thank you :).